# Retrieve data first in order to set default form values? (Angular2)

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-http

**The Problem**

I'm setting up quite a complicated form, and each time I submit a PATCH request the values reset to null.

In the form control when I try to set the default value to data loaded in the service it will not work, as the data is not available straight away/has not been saved to `public model = Model[]`

**The Code**

```
   getControls() {
     let controlObj = {}

     for (var i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
       this.field1 = "field-1-" + i

       testObj[this.field1] = new FormControl({value: this.model.name}, Validators.required)

     }
     this.controls = testObj
     return this.controls;
   }



   ngOnInit() {

     this.myService.getData()
       .subscribe(
         settings => {
           this.model = model;
           console.log(this.model)

         },
         error => console.error(error)
       )

     console.log(this.model)


     this.settingsForm = new FormGroup(
       this.getControls()
     )

   }

 }
```

**Summary**

`new FormControl({value: this.model.name}` cannot retrieve this value as the service does not save the data to be used again inside the component.

Is there a way for me to save the information retrieved from the get request inside the component first before running the rest of the functions?

I'm a little confused as to why the `console.log(this.modal)` inside the service request returns the data, but the one outside returns null.

Let me know if you need more code - I've tried to get away with the bare minimum to avoid confusion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm a little confused as to why the console.log(this.modal) inside the service request returns the data, but the one outside returns null.

Because it is asynchronous process.

`console.log(this.model)` outside `subscribe` probably will executed first before `this.model` receive any value, that is why it display null.

If you want `getControls` executed after `this.model` has value, then change your code to

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.getData()
       .subscribe(
         settings => {
            this.model = model;
            this.settingsForm = new FormGroup(
               this.getControls()
            )   
         },
         error => console.error(error)
       );
}
```

Comment: I did think that initially but it wasn't working, (came up with a template error) so had to wrap my form inside an ngIf and trigger it after calling the `this.getControls()` inside the subscribe. I'm not sure why it wasn't working when I initially tried it, but thanks for the answer! It's got it working, maybe my ordering was wrong. Thanks !